# "env: php: No such file or directory" on new mac OS Monterey

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

i've updated my mac os to Monterey (12) and then I can not use composer command or php command and get this error

```
env: php: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PHP has been removed from MacOS since v12 (Monterey), so you first need to install it on your own to use it. From my POV, the easiest way to do this is using Homebrew

Answer (score 44):

macOS 12 (Monterey) removes the system provided PHP and you will need to install it yourself.

It is easy to install if you have [brew](https://brew.sh/) installed. Simply run the following:

```
brew install php@7.4 brew-php-switcher
brew link php@7.4
```

This will install the latest version of PHP 7.4 as well as a handy utility for switching between PHP versions if you need to.

Comment: You are my hero

Comment: I had the same problem but had to uninstall Homebrew first and then after a fresh reinstall on Monterey it now works.

Comment: brew link did the trick for me after installing it.

Comment: Wow, it worked. But, be aware that the first command takes a long time to execute the installation. For me, it when at least 10 minutes, and I have a pretty fast internet connection.

Answer (score 4):

run **brew install php** , it will take php last version, then you will be be able to use php on your mac